# Mechanize module is not installing in Windows machine and Ubuntu machine

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

I tried to install Mechanize module in my windows machine and Ubunu, but there was some problems to install Mechanize module. Is there any alternative way to install Mechanize module. Due to following dependencies I could not install Mechanize module.

Some modules that failed are AnyEvent::Future, Future::HTTP, Image::Info, Imager::File::PNG, Object::Import

I am getting following error message:

```
Failed 41/41 test programs. 1/1 subtests failed.
dmake.exe:  Error code 130, while making 'test_dynamic'
  CORION/WWW-Mechanize-Chrome-0.22.tar.gz
5 dependencies missing (AnyEvent::Future,Future::HTTP,Image::Info,Imager::File::PNG,Object::Import); additionally test harness failed
  C:\devhome\tools\perl\site\bin\dmake.exe test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports CORION/WWW-Mechanize-Chrome-0.22.tar.gz
Failed during this command:
 MSCHOUT/Text-Template-1.53.tar.gz            : make_test NO
 LEONT/Software-License-0.103013.tar.gz       : make_test NO one dependency not OK (Text::Template); additionally test harness failed
 BBYRD/Software-License-CCpack-1.11.tar.gz    : make_test NO one dependency not OK (Software::License); additionally test harness failed
 ISHIGAKI/Module-CPANTS-Analyse-0.96.tar.gz   : make_test NO 2 dependencies missing (Software::License,Software::License::CC_BY_SA_3_0); additionally test harness failed
 ETHER/Test-Kwalitee-1.27.tar.gz              : make_test NO one dependency not OK (Module::CPANTS::Analyse); additionally test harness failed
 JONASBN/Test-Timer-2.09.tar.gz               : make_test NO one dependency not OK (Test::Kwalitee)
 PEVANS/AnyEvent-Future-0.03.tar.gz           : make_test NO one dependency not OK (Test::Timer); additionally test harness failed
 CORION/Future-HTTP-0.09.tar.gz               : make_test NO
 SREZIC/Image-Info-1.41.tar.gz                : make_test NO
 TONYC/Imager-File-PNG-0.92.tar.gz            : writemakefile NO 'C:\devhome\tools\perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site' returned status 512
 AMBRUS/Object-Import-1.004.tar.gz            : make_test NO
 CORION/WWW-Mechanize-Chrome-0.22.tar.gz      : make_test NO 5 dependencies missing (AnyEvent::Future,Future::HTTP,Image::Info,Imager::File::PNG,Object::Import); additionally test harness failed
```

Comment: Well, what tests failed?

Comment: What means did you use to install this module, and did you have any problem installing the dependencies?  It's not correct to just download the tarball, unpack it and expect it to work without first working your way up the dependency tree. And that's a lot of work... generally it's much easier to use a tool like cpanm (cpan minus) to deal with pulling in everything needed.

Answer (score 0):

The module name is [WWW::Mechanize::Chrome](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Chrome), not "Mechanize".

You can install WWW::Mechanize::Chrome and all its prerequisites by running

```
cpanm WWW::Mechanize::Chrome
```

or by running

```
cpan install WWW::Mechanize::Chrome
```

This will pull in all the missing prerequisites that the error message above lists. If you find that the module `Object::Import` is failing, you can force the installation. The module failing automatic installation is a known bug.

Comment: Hi Corion, I used cpan to install Mechanize using following command, cpan install WWW::Mechanize::Chrome. But its installation is not succesfule because of following modules, AnyEvent::Future,Future::HTTP,Image::Info,Imager::File::PNG,Object::Import. While installing dependency AnyEvent::Future, installation is not succesful.

Comment: Yes, so the failure is with the `AnyEvent::Future` module. First fix that problem, then come back to `WWW::Mechanize::Chrome`.